# Iframe : Blocked iframe from accessing a cross origin iframe **only in chrome**

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, blocked

I'm calling the top window from inside an iframe. Both are in exactly the same protocol, domain and port.
There's another iframe (from other domain) in the middle, but that shouldnt be a problem.

Tested in Firefox developer edition, it works.
Tested in Edge, it works
Tested in Chrome Canary, it works

It just doesnt work in Chrome (Versión 67.0.3396.87 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Even in Chrome, the test:

```
var origins=window.location.ancestorOrigins; 
var sameOrigin=origins[origins.length-1]==window.origin;
```

sets sameOrigin to true..

Any idea of what may be happening?

Comment: If it's a security issue, you should have something in your developer console.

Comment: The "Blocked iframe from accessing..." appears in that console..